# Pinia with single-spa Microfrontend

Tags: vuejs3, pinia, single-spa

I want to use a vue3 app with Pinia in single-spa. The state should only be available in the one app. In `handleInstace` I create pinia and include it. But since handleInstace is called after the app creation, the following error occurs. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

maint.ts:

```js
import { h, createApp } from 'vue';
import singleSpaVue from 'single-spa-vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import App from './App.vue';

const vueLifecycles = singleSpaVue({
  createApp,
  appOptions: {
    render() {
      return h(App, {
        // single-spa props are available on the "this" object. Forward them to your component as needed.
        // https://single-spa.js.org/docs/building-applications#lifecycle-props
        // if you uncomment these, remember to add matching prop definitions for them in your App.vue file.
        // name: this.name
      });
    },
  },
  handleInstance(app) {
    const pinia = createPinia();
    app.use(pinia);
  },
  replaceMode: false,
});

export const bootstrap = vueLifecycles.bootstrap;
export const mount = vueLifecycles.mount;
export const unmount = vueLifecycles.unmount;
```

error:

```
single-spa-layout.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: application '@b-velop/measurement' died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
    const pinia = createPinia()
    app.use(pinia)
This will fail in production.
    at useStore (pinia.mjs:1707:19)
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/babel-loader@8.3.0_@babel+core@7.22.10_webpack@5.88.2/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!../../node_modules/.pnpm/ts-loader@9.4.4_typescript@4.5.5_webpack@5.88.2/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-41.use[1]!../../node_modules/.pnpm/vue-loader@17.2.2_vue@3.3.4_webpack@5.88.2/node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/SensorView.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts (SensorView.vue:4:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/components/SensorView.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts (App.vue:1:456)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/components/SensorView.vue (App.vue:25:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
```

Comment: Hello!  I am in no position to answer your question.  I can, however, give you an alternative:  Use a simpler-than-Pinia reactive store.  Svelte stores are mega simple, yet reactive.  You don't need Svelte.  You just program your store in vanilla JS.  See [this issue](https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa/issues/1111) where I describe the process.